# Import your Mac AddressBook Contacts into the iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, contacts

I need a big list of contacts for some testing and I wanted to import the addressBook contacts that I have into the iOS simulator. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: This should work: http://www.developerscamp.com/mobile/iphone/how-to-import-contacts-into-the-iphone-simulator.html Tested it with Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6.0.